# Handling EOF when subscribing to Event Logs

Tags: go-ethereum, logs, golang

I'm trying to subscribe to events logs to handle `Transfer(address,address,uint64)` events.  I've followed this example.

https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-development-with-go-book/blob/master/en/event-subscribe/README.md

However, when there are no incoming events I get an `EOF` error and the app quits. I tried to prevent the app quitting by removing the log.Fatal(err).  However, any subsequent JSON-RPC call to the blockchain will result in write `tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:42542->xx.xx.xx.xx:443: i/o timeout` errors.  Is there any way to close the socket gracefully without quitting the app?

Basically what I want to do is to continuously subscribe to the event and recover from any errors.

Comment: can't you just add a check for if `err == io.EOF`?

Comment: I too am getting this. I'm paginating through a range of blocks for events _(since querying too far back pulls too much data)_, and within a certain range of blocks I get this error. The EOF error is wrapped up, so a simple `err == io.EOF` doesn't catch =(   The only way I've been able to get through events within these blocks is to query an extremely small range of blocks _(like ~10 blocks at a time)_